# No keyboard after 18.04 boot - but ok after reconnect

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard

I've a clean install of ubuntu 18.04 (configured as Kubuntu).  All updates have been applied as of this date. On cold boot the usb keyboard says it is detected by the bios but by login the keyboard is not working. The solution is to unplug and plug in the keyboard after which it functions correctly.  On boot the usb mouse does not have this problem. Similarly with the external usb disc this is not accessible until it is opened in the file manager.  This seems to be an issue with usb device manager.  Is there a solution? Whilst unplugging and reconnecting is not too onerous it would be better if it wasn't necessary.